# Algorithmic nullhomotopies

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $Y$ be a $1$-reduced finite simplicial set, $\Sigma^n$ be a simplicial model of the $n$-sphere and $f: \Sigma^n\to Y$. We further know that $f$ is nullhomotopic (this can be algorithmically verified via obstruction theory and Postnikov towers such as in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3093)).

Our goal is to construct an explicit simplicial extension $F: B^{n+1}\to Y$ of $f$ such that $B^{n+1}$ is a triangulation of the $(n+1)$-disc and $\partial B^{n+1}$ is a simplicial subdivision of $\Sigma^n$.

Such algorithm clearly exists, as one could add one vertex to $\Sigma^n$ to create a simplicial model of $B^{n+1}$, then do iterative barycentric subdivisions and "try" all simplicial maps to $Y$ and eventually succeed.

Is there a more feasible algorithm with, let's say, polynomial complexity?

If we replace $Y$ via its Postnikov tower $P_{n+1}$ and replace $f$ by $(\varphi f)$ where $\varphi: Y\to P_{n+1}$ is $n$-connected, then we can construct an extension $B^{n+1}\to P_{n+1}$ explicitely, see, for example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6444). However, we don't see how to find a nullhomotopy/extension to $Y$, which in general is not Kan.

Comment: Well, the first problem is that the volume of the filling ball may be exponential in the volume of the sphere.

Comment: @HJRW Thanks; can you please elaborate on that? Actually, I don't even see how to create an "exponential" filling (or how to prove it exists).

Comment: The standard example occurs in the presentation complex of the $(1,2)$-Bausmlag--Solitar group $\langle a,b\mid bab^{-1}=a^2\rangle$.  The loop corresponding to the word $a^{-1}b^kab^{-k}ab^{k}a^{-1}b^{-1}$ is filled by a disk with area of the order of $2^k$. (And worse, in any group with unsolvable word problem, the filling area is a non-recursive function of the length of the loop.) See Proposition 3.2.2 of Bridson's article 'The geometry of the word problem'...

Comment: ... The article also contains lots of references.  Much less is known about 'higher dimensional' filling functions, but I'm fairly certain they can be superpolynomial.  https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/bridson/papers/bfs

Comment: Correction: Bau*msl*ag.

Comment: @HJRW Maybe I should have emphasised that I mean higher homotopies, not the fundamental group. For the nullhomotopic $1$-loops, there is no recursively computable bound for the filling, as you yourself pointed out.

Comment: Sure.  I'm fairly certain the fillings can still be exponential in size, though haven't found a reference in a brief search.  Perhaps someone else knows one?

Comment: I would be happy even with a (simply) exponential bound...

Comment: On reflection, the literature I'm thinking of is about aspherical spaces.  Probably the suspension of the presentation complex of the Bamslag--Solitar group gives an example with exponential 2nd filling function. And similarly, the suspension for a group with worse Dehn function should give a larger 2nd filling function.